# jquery datatable repeating same results

Tags: 2010, jquery-ui

`

```
var _web = null;
var _clientContext = null;
var ShoutoutDataSub = [];
var Name = null;
var fromDate = null;
$(function () {

    $("#ShootOutfrmDate").datepicker();
    $("#ShootOutToDate").datepicker();
    $("#ShootOutfrmDate").css({ "width": "135px" });
    $("#ShootOutToDate").css({ "width": "135px" });

});

function Init() {

    _clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    _web = _clientContext.get_web();

    $("#btnGetResults").click(function () {
         Name = $('#txtEmp').val();
         fromDate = $('#ShootOutfrmDate').val();
        GetReports(Name, fromDate);

    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).ready(function () { ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(Init, "sp.js"); });

});

function GetReports(empName, fromDate) {

    var listShoutouts = _web.get_lists().getByTitle("Shout outs");
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
   // camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name="ShoutOutTo" /><Value Type="User">' + empName + '</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name="Created" /><Value IncludeTimeValue="FALSE" Type="DateTime">' + fromDate + '</Value></Eq></And></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="Modified" Ascending="True" /></OrderBy></Query></View>');
   // camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Neq><FieldRef Name="ID" /><Value Type="Number">0</Value></Neq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="Title"/></OrderBy></Query></View>');
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><And><Neq><FieldRef Name="ID" /><Value Type="Number">0</Value></Neq><Eq><FieldRef Name="_ModerationStatus" /><Value Type="ModStat">0</Value></Eq></And></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="_ModerationStatus" Ascending="True" /></OrderBy></Query></View>');
    this.ShoutoutsListItemCol = listShoutouts.getItems(camlQuery);
    _clientContext.load(ShoutoutsListItemCol);
    _clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onGetReportsSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onGetReportsFailed));

}

function onGetReportsSuccess() {

    try {
        var empName;
        //var appstatus = "";
        //var mod;
        var enumerator = ShoutoutsListItemCol.getEnumerator();

        while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
            var listItem = enumerator.get_current();
            empName = listItem.get_item("ShoutOutTo").get_lookupValue();
            //var action = listItem.get_item("_ModerationStatus");
            var Title = listItem.get_item("Title");
            var createdOn = listItem.get_item("Created");
            //action = "_ModStat";
            var appStatus = ["Approved", "Denied", "Pending", "Draft", "Scheduled"];
            var modStatAsNumber = 0;
            var modStatAsText = appStatus[modStatAsNumber];
            //set approval status to Approved (0)
            //ListItem.set_item('_ModerationStatus', 0);

            if (empName === Name)
             {
                var newItem = {};
                newItem["Employee"] = empName;
               // newItem["Action"] = Title;
                newItem["CreatedOn"] = createdOn;
                newItem["_ModerationStatus"] = modStatAsText;
                ShoutoutDataSub.push(newItem);
            }

        }
        $("#tblShootOutReport").empty();
       var  shootOut = $("#tblShootOutReport").DataTable({
            "aaData": ShoutoutDataSub,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bPaginate": false,
            "oLanguage": {
                "sEmptyTable": "No Items to show",
                "sInfoEmpty": ""
            },
            "sDom": '<"top">f<"bottom"><"clear">',
            "aoColumns": [{ "sTitle": "Employee Name", "mData": "Employee", "sWidth": "10%" },
                        { "sTitle": "Approval Status", "mData": "_ModerationStatus", "sWidth": "10%" },
                        { "sTitle": "Created Date", "mData": "CreatedOn", "sWidth": "8%" }
                        ],
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "bSort": true,
            "bAutoWidth": true,
            "iDisplayLength": 100,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",                
            "bStateSave": true,
            "bDestroy": true
        });

    }
    catch (err) {
        alert(err);
    }
}

function onGetReportsFailed(sender, args) {
    alert("Failed to load results..");

}
```

`I am working on SharePoint 2010, I have a list data that  am displaying in a seperate page using jquery datatable but when i click on button it is giving me repeated results how to make it show only the same  result even the button is clicked multiple times.The issue here when i click the results button twice or more the result is duplicating mutliple times. Please refer the figure for my scenario [image]

Comment: Without seeing relevant code no one can help you.

Comment: Hi Amal sorry forgot to post the code...updated the code let me know any work around thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating click event as follows

```
$("#btnGetResults").click(function () {
    ShoutoutDataSub = [];
    Name = $('#txtEmp').val();
    fromDate = $('#ShootOutfrmDate').val();
    GetReports(Name, fromDate);
});
```

Comment: Hi Amal Thanks a ton worked like a charm ....sorry to ask this am just learning things in jquery what does it do when u say ShoutoutDataSub = []?

Comment: Amal can I get the same thing of pullling data from list using jquery to html table instead of jquery data table? thanks in advance.

Comment: It clears the array of objects. So before each click we are clearing and loading. This way previous result will not get repeated.

Comment: Yes you can create HTML table dynamically. But this require you to write extra lines of code.

Comment: Am having a column in the same list as above which is "createdby"(Person or group ) and it should be displayed below after button click same as above just an extra column and there is condition for anonymous here if the person name exists it whould be displayed else it should be displayed as anonymous. do u have nay idea for this..thank u

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you aren't flushing the datatable content prior to loading the new data,

```
$("#datatable").empty();
//refetch and populate datatable
```